# Remove newline in the middle of CSV file

Tags: csv, awk, sed, replace, newline

I need to clean a CSV file looking like this :

```
food;1;ZZ;"lipsum";NR
foobar;123;NA;"asking 
price";NR
foobar;5;NN;Random text;NN
moongoo;13;VV;"Any label";OO
```

Yes sometimes without a double quote, but the new line occurs only with double quote fields.
The issue happens only with the 4th field.

I work on an awk command and it's now what I have :

```
awk '{ if (substr($4,1,1) == "\"" && substr($4,length($4)) != "\"") gsub(/\n/," ");}' FS=";" input_file
```

This awk looks if the first char of the field is a double quote and if the last one isn't a double quote.
Then try to remove the new line but it clearly didn't remove it.

I think I miss a little "easy" thing but can't figure out what is it.

Comment: Can your quoted fields contain any `;`s or `"`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk -F';' -v ORS= '1; {print (NF==4 ? " " : "\n")}' file

food;1;ZZ;"lipsum";NR
foobar;123;NA;"asking price";NR
foobar;5;NN;Random text;NN
moongoo;13;VV;"Any label";OO
```

**How it works:**

- This command sets `ORS` to empty character initially.
- Then for each line it prints full record.
- Then it prints a space when `NF == 4` otherwise it prints a line break.

Comment: works perfecly, thanks for the explanation and not only submit the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

One idea for tweaking OP's current `awk` code:

```
awk -F';' '
{ if (substr($4,1,1) == "\"" && substr($4,length($4)) != "\"") {    # if we have an incomplete line then ...
     printf $0                                                      # printf, sans a "\n", will leave the cursor at the end of the current line
     next                                                           # skip to next line of input
  }
}
1                                                                   # otherwise print current line
' input_file

# or as a one-liner sans comments:

awk -F';' ' { if (substr($4,1,1) == "\"" && substr($4,length($4)) != "\"") { printf $0; next } } 1 ' input_file
```

This generates:

```
food;1;ZZ;"lipsum";NR
foobar;123;NA;"asking price";NR
foobar;5;NN;Random text;NN
moongoo;13;VV;"Any label";OO
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez 's/(;"[^"]*)\n/\1/g' input_file
food;1;ZZ;"lipsum";NR
foobar;123;NA;"asking price";NR
foobar;5;NN;Random text;NN
moongoo;13;VV;"Any label";OO
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for `RT`:

```
$ awk -v RS='"' '!(NR%2){gsub(/\n/,"")} {ORS=RT} 1' file
food;1;ZZ;"lipsum";NR
foobar;123;NA;"asking price";NR
foobar;5;NN;Random text;NN
moongoo;13;VV;"Any label";OO
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;/^[^\"]*(\\.[^\"]*)*("[^\"]*(\\.[^"\]*)*"[^\"]*)*"[^\"]*(\\.[^"\]*)*$/{N;s/\n//;ta}' file
```

This matches any unbalanced double quotes (with or without escaped double quotes), appends the following line, removes the newline and repeats until the double quotes are balanced.

---

A simpler solution in which escaped double quotes are forgone:

```
sed -E ':a;/^[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*"[^"]*$/{N;s/\n//;ta}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'food;1;ZZ;"lipsum";NR
      foobar;123;NA;"asking
      price";NR
      foobar;5;NN;Random text;NN
      moongoo;13;VV;"Any label";OO' |
```

> ```
> mawk '(ORS = (_<ORS)==(NF % 2) ? RS : _)^_' FS=';' | gcat -n
> ```

```
 1  food;1;ZZ;"lipsum";NR
 2  foobar;123;NA;"asking price";NR
 3  foobar;5;NN;Random text;NN
 4  moongoo;13;VV;"Any label";OO
```